# How to create Rails app without comments in files like Gemfile and etc?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Are there any parameters to pass to `rails new <app_name>` so new app will not have a lot of comments in generated files? Or maybe there is some other way to delete all those comments automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to create the rails app without comments

Actually it is a good practice to have the comments, and then you can delete them one by one if you want

Answer (score 0):

The Rails app generator does not have an option to remove comments. The comments themselves are part of the [code templates](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/b2eb1d1c55a59fee1e6c4cba7030d8ceb524267c/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/templates) which the generator uses to generate the files like `config/application.rb`.

Rails does let you setup your own [application templates](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html#application-templates) [and generators](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html#creating-your-first-generator) which could be used to this end but its a large and not very worthwhile endeavour. Comments are actually very helpful when you introduce new members to a team or just forget what a configuration option does.

> Or maybe there is some other way to delete all those comments automatically?

That leaves options like [grep](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) which could be used to search and delete lines starting with `#`. But again the comments are actually helpful and there are better things to spend your time on.